# Hiding Quads with PShape with Texture in Processing

Tags: textures, processing

I'm using the following code to create a globe:

```java
PImage imgmap;
PShape globe;

void setup() {
size(1000,1000,P3D);
imgmap = loadImage("earth.jpg");
globe = createShape(SPHERE, 300);
globe.setTexture(imgmap);
}

void draw(){
background(0);
translate (500,500);  
shape (globe);
}
```

Well, everything works as hoped BUT I can still see the underlying geometric structure.

How can I hide the quad and trig lines from view?

Many thanks in advance etc...

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can change the stroke colour of the sphere to full transparency in setup():

```
  globe.setStroke(color(255,0));
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I have voted you each a "+" but as I've a score of less than 15, they don't show up unfortunately. Anyway, much appreciated - Simon

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call the `noStroke()` function before calling `createShape()`:

```java
  noStroke();
  globe = createShape(SPHERE, 300);
```

This tells Processing to not even bother drawing the stroke (the lines).

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/noStroke_.html).

Comment: A neater solution than mine. Once `createShape()` has been called, `noStroke()` has no more effect on the drawn `PShape`, hence `setStroke()` would be needed.